# When was the five day Schengen Transit Visa (type B) abolished?

Tags: schengen-visas

The original [Schengen agreement](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=celex:42000A0922%2802%29) mentions

> a transit visa authorising its holder to pass through the territories of the Contracting Parties once, twice or exceptionally several times en route to the territory of a third State, provided that no transit shall exceed five days.

It would seem this no longer exist (see for example https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa_en). When was it abolished?

Comment: Why do you assume it was abolished from that link?

Comment: Because it is no longer listed. I looked at quite a few documents, none of them lists it. This [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98671/transit-visa-process-on-a-pakistani-passport#comment236705_98675) from 2017 casually mentions it too.

Comment: Is this a travel or a history question?

Comment: mmmm travel? There are still a good number of websites referring to it, including the first result for Frequently Asked Questions about Schengen Visa in Google which we know to be a very outdated site but not everyone does. I am trying to set the record straight here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to travel. The transit visa *is* abolished. It is if no significance for current or future travellers *when* that happened.

Comment: It sure is. Everyone will otherwise just argue that the source we point to is incomplete. It's hard to prove a negative. The easiest to prove it is by pointing to the legal text abolishing it. Have you not seen the first comment _in this very thread_?

Comment: @chx In that case, your question is wether or not the transit visa has been abolished or not, that would indeed be relevant and on-topic, but that is not what you are asking. I am still of the opinion that it is of absolutely no significance *when* that happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/stranieri/ingressosoggiornoinitalia/visto_ingresso/tipologie_visto_durata.html) seems to indicate it was abolished on 5/4/2010 with the entry into force of [EC810/2009](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:243:0001:0058:EN:PDF):

> Pursuant to the Visa Code ([EC Regulation no. 810/2009](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:243:0001:0058:EN:PDF), which entered into effect on 5 April 2010)
>
> [...]
>
> Transit (type B), type of visa abolished by the above Visa Code. As of 5 April 2010 Transit visas are all type C

Note that the text of the regulation makes no reference I could find to that type of visa, so I can't say for sure whether they were abolished at this time or previously.

It seems type B visas were still issued at the border (but with great difficulty) around 2006 (see https://journals.openedition.org/conflits/15743, point 31), though.