# What is the time limit for transit at the Schengen airport?

Tags: schengen, transit

Citizens of most countries do not require a transit visa when transiting through an airport in the Schengen area ([Source](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy/who-must-apply-schengen-visa_de)). Schengen transit visas are also discussed extensively in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area).

However one thing is not clear to me: In case I do not need a transit visa, what is the maximum amount of time I may spend in transit at the Schengen airport? Is there any time limit?

Comment: If you don’t need a transit visa, and in the absence of a specific rule (which could be country-specific), in theory the maximum amount of time is the limit on visa-free entry, one would imagine. However, the typical stance is likely to be based on the *reasonableness* of the journey and the use of a particular transit airport. Looking at the timescales for TWOV in general might be a good guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Visa code](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/system/files/2020-02/visa-code-consolidated-version.pdf) is has nothing on this but it's instructive:

> In the examination of an application for an airport transit visa, the
> consulate or the central authorities shall in particular verify:

> (a) that the travel document presented is not false, counterfeit or forged;

> (b) the points of departure and destination of the third-country national
> concerned and **the coherence of the intended itinerary and airport
> transit**;

emphasis mine

> (c) proof of the onward journey to the final destination.

> The examination of an application shall be based notably on the
> authenticity and reliability of the documents submitted and on the
> veracity and reliability of the statements made by the applicant.

As always: trying to outsmart the authorities will not work. Their decision power is wide and (almost) absolute. (Almost: there are legal remedies but good luck winning a legal battle that your planned one month stay inside Frankfurt Airport was a "transit".)

There's no set amount of hours but I'd strongly suspect more than 24 hours would require extensive documentation and more than 48 is very near impossible. Extremely weird edge cases always exist -- if you are coming from some place with flights only every few days and your destination is also such and they mismatch then there's a chance you can gain an ATV visa stretching several days. I would even carefully say it's not unlikely this is the very reason why hours were not set. Once again: document extensively. But do not try to pull a Mehran Karimi Nasseri, it won't work.

Another guideline: the Type B visa abolished in 2009/2010 (see this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/145144/4188) ) was five days and so the ATV is very likely to be intended to be no longer than that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For Morocco -> Ecuador, the only sane option seemed to be a 20 hour layover in Madrid, which is why I was asking ("sane" being very relative here!).

Comment: I am not a visa official but that can't be a problem in itself. That's totally normal. Once a day flights are normal for transoceanic trips and so this can easily occur. In a similar vein, for example, the Rio De Janeiro - Amsterdam flight lands at 2:25PM while the Amsterdam - Nairobi flight leaves at 1:05PM so a similarly long layover is in the cards and there are quite a few reasons why would one choose this routing to get from Rio De Janeiro to Nairobi.

Comment: Just for coherence, the original question is about the case where the traveller does **not** need a transit visa. Though I would think the the reasoning is about the same.